# How to clear a ComboBox after research WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I had a research by criteria with Two combobox, it works fine
after the research is finished, I have a button Display All : to reset the combobox to null..and the DataGrid display with all elements ,

The problem that the combobox must be empty when I click on the Button Dispaly All!

- Without select an element in combobox(just dispaly the datagrid):I have 6 elements in the datagrid, it is correct..and the combobox are Empty
- After select the Search criteria, i have the result correct: (I have just 3 results, it is the correct action)
  [3 elements picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A6zh.png)
- When I click on the button Display All:(I have all the elements in datagrid, 6 elements..It is correct) But the Combobox aren't empty!!
  [6 elements picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm67v.png)

The view:

```
 <Window x:Class="WPFAuthentification.Views.BusinesseventsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" >   

     <Label Content="Entity Type" Width="128" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
     <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding EntityLevelEnum}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding EntityType, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, TargetNullValue=''}"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"  />


        <Button Content="Dislplay all" ToolTip="Display All Business Events" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"  Command="{Binding Initialize}" 
                Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowDisplayAllButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"  />

         <DataGrid ..... />
</Window>
```

The ViewModel:

```
class BusinesseventsViewModel : ViewModelBase1
    {

        private ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass> businessEventsList;    

        private RelayCommand<string> initialize;
        public RelayCommand<string> Initialize
        {
            get { return initialize; }
        }       
        public BusinesseventsViewModel()
        {
            //businessEventsList: to Get all the Business events
            businessEventsList = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass>(WCFclient.getAllBusinessEvent());
            //Enumeration of Entity Type and Criticality
            levelCriticalityEnum = new ObservableCollection<Level_Criticality>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Level_Criticality)).Cast<Level_Criticality>());
            entityLevelEnum = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEntityLevel>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(BusinessEntityLevel)).Cast<BusinessEntityLevel>());
            //the Button Display All :
            initialize = new RelayCommand<string>(initFunc);    
       }        

       //Function of the Button Display All
        private void initFunc(object obj)
        {
            EntityType = null;
            OnPropertyChanged("EntityLevelEnum");
            Criticality = null;
            OnPropertyChanged("Criticality");
        }     

         private string  entityType;
        public string EntityType
        {
            get { return entityType; }
            set
            {
                entityType = value;
                businessEventsList = filterByCriteria(entityType, criticality);
                OnPropertyChanged("BusinessEventsList");
                OnPropertyChanged("EntityType");
            }
        } 

             //Function of the research :
                 public ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass> filterByCriteria(string entityType, string criticality)
        {               
            BusinessEventsList = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass>(WCFclient.getAllBusinessEvent());         

            ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass> updatedList = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass>();

            if ((entityType == null) && (Criticality == null))
            {
                updatedList = businessEventsList;
            }          

            if ((entityType != null && entityType != "") && (Criticality != null))
                {
                    updatedList = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass>(BusinessEventsList.Where(a => a.EntityType.ToString().ToLower().Equals(criticality.ToString())
                                                                             && a.Critciality.ToString().Equals(criticality.ToString())));
                }          

        }
```

Comment: you never clear entityLevelEnum  ???

Comment: Thanks, I add EntityLevelEnum = null;         
   OnPropertyChanged("EntityLevelEnum");it works,the combobox is Empty...
 but after that when i want to select new element in Combbox.. the combobox of EntityLevelEnum  still Empty!

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Using GalaSoft.MvvmLight I did this, and works without problem;

Window.cs content:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    }
}

public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _selectedItem;


    public RelayCommand Command { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> ItemsSource { get; }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { Set(ref _selectedItem, value); }
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Command = new RelayCommand(() => SelectedItem = null);
        ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string> { "index 0", "index 1", "index 2", "index 3" };
    }
}
```

and my Window.xaml content

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testClean:TestViewModel}">
            <Grid>
                <Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="HotPink">just some pink text</TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
                <ComboBox Height="50" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20" SelectedIndex="0" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding Command}" Height="50" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,20,20,20">Reset</Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
```

Tested and working as expected (when you put null as SelectedItem the combobox returns empty)

Comment: thanks,
but I did the same thing in my implementation, just SelectedItem I rename it to EntityType ..
The problem that I want to make the combobox empty..then when I can select an new item from the list in this combobox

Comment: for instance, try creating a new project.
Add the GalaSoft.MVVMLight from nuget and try this code, It works as intended (and as you want)